# Weight of a graph based on bridges connecting $L$ and $R$ sides

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms

This is about weighted graphs. Given a graph $G = (V, E)$ and $V = L \cup R$ with $L\cap R =\emptyset$. A bridge between $L$ and $R$ is any edge with an endpoint in $L$ and the other endpoint in $R$, connecting what would be the "left side" of the graph, with a given set of vertices, to the "right side" of the graph. The goal is to find the minimum weight of all bridges.

Let $L=\{a,d,h\}$
and $R=\{b,c,e,f\}$
over this graph:
[image]

(a) Which of the following are bridges between $L$ and $R$ in the graph $G$? Select all that apply.

(I know the answer is A, D, E. This answer is correct according to the homework answer sheet. Please go to part b.)

A. $\{a,e\}$

B. $\{a,d\}$

C. $\{d,f\}$

D. $\{d,e\}$

E. $\{e,h\}$

b) What is the minimum weight among ALL bridges between $L$ and $R$?

According to the professor, the answer of b) is $3$. I don't understand why.
PLEASE HELP! I have a test tomorrow.
Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. The edge $(a, b)$ must be in every MST, and there's no edge between L and R with a lower value. Also, your solution to the first question doesn't seem correct — $(d, e)$ isn't in the MST

Comment: HI, thank you for your answer. I have these answers from the professor. I did come to the ADE answer myself first, and it marked as correct, then I asked the Professor and he confirmed. This is about weighted graphs. I will edit the question

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

Letter b) is asking what the minimum weight is given **all edges** present on the graph, and not only the ones mentioned on letter a).

The edges with the smallest weight that can connect **L** to **R** as a bridge are *{a, b}* and *{h, f}* and they both have weight = 3.